# ansible to find latest files from a directory recursively

Tags: ansible

I have a requirement wherein I need to recursively search a directory for certain files. Then in each sub-directory where there is a match, just get the latest file.

Suppose this is a directory structure:

[image: Directory Structure]

Now as you see I have highlighted latest `*.txt` files in both sub-directories `A` and `B`, while `C` has none.

My code below will get all `*.txt` files from sub-directories. I just can't figure out how to only get latest files using Ansible and avoiding shell script.

```yaml
  - name: Ansible find file examples
    find:
      paths: "/home/sarah/demo/"
      patterns: "*txt"
      recurse: yes
    register: files_matched

  - name: Get latest file
    set_fact:
      latest_file: "{{ files_matched.files | sort(attribute='mtime',reverse=true) }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{latest_file|map(attribute='path')|list}}"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a list for this with a condition based on the [`dirname`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) and the `dirname` of what is in the list already (thanks to the help of the filter [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map)).

With the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
      - find:
          paths: /home/sarah/demo
          patterns: "*.txt"
          recurse: yes
        register: files_matched

      - set_fact:
          latest_files: "{{ latest_files | default([])  + [item.path] }}"
        loop: "{{ files_matched.files | sort(attribute='mtime', reverse=true) }}"
        when: "item.path | dirname not in latest_files | default([]) | map('dirname')"
        ## 
        # The loop_control is just there for validation purpose
        ##
        loop_control:
          label: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' | strftime(item.mtime) }} {{ item.path }}"

      - debug:
          var: latest_files
```

This gives me the recap:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [find] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=2021-03-15 14:07:10 /home/sarah/demo/B/b1.txt)
ok: [localhost] => (item=2021-03-15 14:06:16 /home/sarah/demo/A/a2.txt)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=2021-03-15 14:06:05 /home/sarah/demo/B/b.txt) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=2021-03-15 14:05:46 /home/sarah/demo/A/a.txt) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=2021-03-15 14:05:38 /home/sarah/demo/A/a1.txt)  

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  latest_files:
  - /home/sarah/demo/B/b1.txt
  - /home/sarah/demo/A/a2.txt

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

All this reproducing your files structure:

```
A:
total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 15 14:05 a.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 15 14:05 a1.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 15 14:06 a2.txt

B:
total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 15 14:06 b.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 15 14:07 b1.txt

C:
total 0
```

Comment: Hi @β.εηοιτ.βε Thank you so much. This is awesome and I after doing a basic Ansible course assumed I could do almost all tasks. Its obvious I need to focus on Jinja2 programming. Could you please recommend some course to master this part of ansible?

Comment: Well the whole Jinja documentation stands on this page: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/ and there is a collection of extra Jinja features (test, filters, ...) built by Ansible that you can read there: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_templating.html.

Comment: β.εηοιτ.βε: Thank you so much. I wish I had words to better express myself.